Googlebot (?) started to abuse my website
My website is a search engine, and Google Search Console has started to gather a lot of nonsensical searches. E.g. someone repeatedly typing in "yaнтEHтoEHфycкEHëyeлeлeлeлeлeлeлeлeлeлeлeлeлeлeл" in the searchbar. (1000s of pages look like this)
The user agent is Googlebot smartphone.
What is going on? Can I somehow reach out to Google that they probably have a bug or something, or that someone is impersonating them...

Have you verified that these are actually coming from Google? And Google is not going to care if somebody is impersonating that as they cannot do anything about it.
